# dual basis of cohomology algebra

Tags: algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $H^*(M)$ be the cohomology algebra of oriented manifold $M$ with rational coefficients.

Let $\{b_i\}$ be a basis of $H^*(M)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let the dual basis be 
$\{d'_i\}$ such that $b_i\smile d_j=\delta_{i,j}w$, where $\smile$ is the cup product of $H^*(M)$ and $w$ the orientation class of $M$.

Suppose $M=\mathbb{C}P^m$.

Then $H^*(M)=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{m+1})$, $|x|=2$.

Choose $b_i=x^i$ for $i=1,\cdots, m$.

How to compute $d_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,m$?

Comment: Is $d_i'=d_i$? Should this be the definition?

Comment: Note also that the defining formula only makes sense if $|b_i|+|d_j| = dim(M)$.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the element $d_i$ which is dual to $x^i$. Now your "orientation class" will be either $+$ or $-x^m$. Then, since you know the product structure, you see that $x^i \smile x^{m-i} = x^m \in H^{2m}\mathbb CP^m$, so we get $\pm x^{m-i}$ as $d_i$ (the sign depending on orientation and the element $x$).